# Ruby class evaluation, validates_inclusion_of with dynamic data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

If I have an ActiveRecord model as follows

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_inclusion_of :value, :in => self.allowed_types

  def self.allowed_types
    # some code that returns an enumerable
  end
end
```

This doesn't work because the allowed_types method hasn't been defined at the time where the validation is evaluated. All the fixes I can think of basically all revolve around moving the method definition above the validation so that it's available when needed.

I appreciate that this may be more of a coding style question than anything (I want all my validations at the top of the model and methods at the bottom) but I feel there should be some kind of solution to this, possibly involving lazy evaluation of the initial model load?

is what I want to do even possible? Should I just be defining the method above the validation or is there a better validation solution to acheive what I want.

Comment: @eightbitraptor...try `:in => Foo.allowed_types` instead of `:in => self.allowed_types`...beacause I think `self` would be referencing the object of `Foo` instead of `Foo`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to use the `lambda` syntax for this purpose. Perhaps like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_inclusion_of :value, :in => lambda { |foo| foo.allowed_types }

  def allowed_types
    # some code that returns an enumerable
  end
end
```

This way it will evaluate the lambda block at every validation and pass the instance of Foo to the block. It will then return the value from allowed_types in that instance so that it can be validated dynamically.

Also note that I removed `self.` from the allowed_types method declaration because that would create a class method instead of an instance method which is what you want here.

Comment: excellent thanks, that was exactly where I was trying to go with that, just didn't realise that passing an object into the lambda would pass the object being validated.

Comment: You may use `:in => lambda(&:allowed_types)` for an even more compact syntax.

Comment: And with the new Lambda syntax: `validates_inclusion_of :value, in: ->(o) { o.allowed_types }`

Answer (score 0):

The :in option of the validates_inclusion_of method doesn't seem to accept a lambda or Proc.  Here's another approach:

```
validates_each :product_id do |record, attrib, value|
  begin
    Product.find(value)
  rescue ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError
    record.errors.add attrib, 'must be selected from list.'
  end
end
```